# How can I find the AOP Advice used for @Transactional?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aop, spring-aop

How can I see the AOP Advice used for @Transactional from Spring framework. I'm using Intellij, and using command Ctrl + click I can go to Transactional interface and here is created the annotation Transactional ant it looks like here:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface Transactional {
    @AliasFor("transactionManager")
    String value() default "";

    @AliasFor("value")
    String transactionManager() default "";

    String[] label() default {};

    Propagation propagation() default Propagation.REQUIRED;

    Isolation isolation() default Isolation.DEFAULT;

    int timeout() default -1;

    String timeoutString() default "";

    boolean readOnly() default false;

    Class<? extends Throwable>[] rollbackFor() default {};

    String[] rollbackForClassName() default {};

    Class<? extends Throwable>[] noRollbackFor() default {};

    String[] noRollbackForClassName() default {};
}
```

But I want to see the Before Advice because I want to see how is it implemented. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Transactional annotation processing is a complex process in Spring, involving many classes. To put it simply, one of the BeanPostProcessor in the postProcessAfterInstantiation method creates an object proxy by wrapping the method in a transaction. But to point to a specific place where this happens is quite problematic, since there are quite a lot of things going on there. If you need more details, then `InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` class specifically does this. You can look at the class methods in its hierarchy and, for example, set breakpoints and see the entire building process in debug mode